# kubernative used memory is more than actul used

Tags: java, kubernetes, memory-management, performance-testing, kubectl

we have a pplication which taking total RSS memory 15GB(calculated through ps -aux) while in kubernative it show 18.5GB(output of kubectl top pods -n $namepace) not sure why taking 3.5 GB memory . How kubernative calculate the used memory . I have taken the output of  /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.stat but not sure how to kubernative calculate the total used memory. how can we investigate this issue. Memory limit set 20GB when reached pods restrted automatilly wwhile there is no issue with applicated hosted on it.

Trying to identify the memory issue of kubernative